# Potential CM database inconsistency, time jump

Tags: ios, xcode, datetime, crash, provisioning-profile

My iOS app is getting crashed when I change device time to future (*i.e. 1/2 years ahead*). The crash log has no relation to my application. **Note** that I tried to launch some of the other 3rd party apps with future time setting and found them facing similar crashes while being launched. Although, some other 3rd party apps did launch successfully.

#### Crashlog

```
{"bug_type":"288","timestamp":"2021-01-26 01:14:49.72 -0500","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.1.3 (17A878)","incident_id":"72A0D729-FD14-499B-A717-C7269B913311"}
{
  "build" : "iPhone OS 13.1.3 (17A878)",
  "product" : "iPhone8,2",
  "kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Tue Sep  3 21:52:19 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.2.3~2\/RELEASE_ARM64_S8000",
  "tuning" : {

  },
  "incident" : "72A0D1D9-FD14-499B-A717-C7269B913311",
  "crashReporterKey" : "98c9539999c967030a9d949965f1531e902b9a5b",
  "date" : "2021-01-26 01:14:49.71 -0500",
  "reason" : "Potential CM database inconsistency, time jump",
  "frontmostPids" : [
    54
  ],
  "exception" : "0xd1510c8d",
  "absoluteTime" : 71656775000,
  "memoryStatus" : {"compressorSize":5596,"compressions":77277,"decompressions":55621,"busyBufferCount":0,"pageSize":16384,"memoryPressure":false,"memoryPages":{"active":46717,"throttled":0,"fileBacked":44080,"wired":14520,"purgeable":1673,"inactive":44620,"free":7459,"speculative":2131}},
  "processByPid" : {
    "0" : {
  "timesThrottled" : 0,
  "pageIns" : 0,
  "waitInfo" : [
    "thread 4239: semaphore port 0 with unknown owner",
    "thread 4248: semaphore port 0 with unknown owner",
    "thread 9636: semaphore port 0 with unknown owner",
    "thread 9643: semaphore port 0 with unknown owner"
  ],
....
```

**Anyone has any idea behind the crash and how can I deal with that crash in my app?**

*Default apps are not facing similar issues.*

### Update

1. The crash happens only for the application I have installed directly from Xcode.
2. The crash does not happen for a fixed future datetime. Sometimes it happens for Feb 2021, sometimes it happens for Mar 2021, etc.
3. Once the crash happens it keeps happening even if I changed the device time to the current date. The only way to avoid crashing is uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: We suspected that might be provisioning profile related bug. Then after some days we did not face any. So far no concrete solution found. :(